# Threaded program hangs on Queue.join() when get() and task_done() passed in as callbacks

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess

This script used to have the Queue as a global object that could be accessed where the threads were being instantiated and in the threaded function itself, but to make things cleaner I refactored things in a more "acceptable" way and instead decided to pass in the Queue's get() and task_done() methods to the threaded function on its instantiation to get rid of the global; however, I'm noticing that join() hangs indefinitely now as a result, whereas before when the Queue was global, it would always run to completion and terminate appropriately.

For full context, here is the source: http://dpaste.com/0PD6SFX

However, here are what I think are the only relevant snippets of code; init is my main method essentially and the class it belongs to possesses the Queue, while run is the method of class Transcode being run (the rest of the Transcode class details aren't relevant, I feel):

```
def __init__(self, kargs):
        self.params = kargs

        # will store generated Transcode objects
        self.transcodes = []

        # Queue to thread ffmpeg processes with
        self.q = Queue.Queue()

        # generate transcodes with self.params for all rasters x formats
        self.generate_transcodes()

        # give the Queue the right number of task threads to make
        for i in range(self.get_num_transcodes()):
            self.q.put(i)

        for transcode in self.transcodes:
            transcode.print_commands()

        # testing code to be sure command strings are generating appropriately
        for transcode in self.transcodes:
            self.q.put(transcode)

        # kick off all transcodes by creating a new daemon (terminating on program close) thread;
        # the thread is given each Transcode's run() method, which is dynamically created within
        # the Transcode constructor given its command strings
        for transcode in self.transcodes:
            t = threading.Thread(target=transcode.run, args=(self.q.get, self.q.task_done))
            t.daemon = True
            t.start()

        print("Transcoding in progress...")

        # go through each transcode and print which process is currently underway, then sleep
        # 1 = first pass, 2 = second pass, 3 = complete
        while True:
            still_running = False
            for transcode in self.transcodes:
                if not transcode.complete:
                    still_running = True
                    print('Transcode %s still running!' % transcode.filename)
                if transcode.current_proc in range(3):
                    print(os.path.basename(transcode.filename) + ': pass %s' % transcode.current_proc)
                else:
                    print(os.path.basename(transcode.filename) + ': complete!')
                print(transcode.complete)
            if not still_running:
                break
            time.sleep(2)
            print('poll')

        # block until all items in queue are gotten and processed
        print('About to join...')
        self.q.join()

        print('End of transcode batch!')

'''
    Executes sequentially the command strings given to this Transcode via subprocess; it will
    first execute one, then the next, as the second command relies on the first being completed.
    It will take in a get() and done() method that are Queue methods and call them at the right
    moments to signify to an external Queue object that the worker thread needed for this instance
    is ready to start and finish.

    @param  get     A Queue get() function to be called at run()'s start.
    @param  done    A Queue done() function to be called at run()'s end.

    @return none
    '''
    def run(self, get, done):
        # get a thread from the queue
        get()

        # convert command lists to command strings
        for i in range(len(self.commands)):
            self.commands[i] = ' '.join(self.commands[i])

        # show that we're working with our first command string
        self.current_proc = 1

        # assign our current proc the first command string subprocess
        self.proc = Popen(self.commands[0], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
        # execute process until complete
        self.proc.communicate()

        print('Transcode %s first pass complete' % self.identifier)

        # run second command string if exists
        if len(self.commands) > 1:

            # show that we're working with second command string
            self.current_proc = 2

            # spawn second process and parse output line by line as before
            self.proc = Popen(self.commands[1], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
            # execute process until complete
            self.proc.communicate()

            print('Transcode %s second pass complete' % self.identifier)

        # delete log files when done
        if self.logfile and os.path.exists(self.logfile + '-0.log'):
            os.remove(self.logfile + '-0.log')
        if self.logfile and os.path.exists(self.logfile + '-0.log.mbtree'):
            os.remove(self.logfile + '-0.log.mbtree')
        if self.logfile and os.path.exists(self.logfile + '-0.log.temp'):
            os.remove(self.logfile + '-0.log.temp')
        if self.logfile and os.path.exists(self.logfile + '-0.log.mbtree.temp'):
            os.remove(self.logfile + '-0.log.mbtree.temp')

        self.complete = True
        print('Transcode %s complete' % self.identifier)

        # assign value of 3 to signify completed task
        self.current_proc = 3

        # finish up with Queue task
        done()
```

Comment: This doesn't reproduce for me with a toy example (creating a queue, loading it with dummy values, passing `q.get` and `q.task_done` to a thread, calling `get`/`done` in that thread, and calling `join` in main thread). Is it possible one of the worker threads is throwing an exception that's preventing `done()` from being called.

Comment: It was actually a silly unrelated mistake on my end; thanks for trying though! Posted the solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very silly: entries were being added to the Queue twice for each of the transcodes taking place.

```
    # give the Queue the right number of task threads to make
    for i in range(self.get_num_transcodes()):
        self.q.put(i)

    # code omitted...

    # testing code to be sure command strings are generating appropriately
    for transcode in self.transcodes:
        self.q.put(transcode)
```

Twas a vestige from refactoring. The Queue therefore thought it needed twice as many worker threads as it actually did and was waiting for its remaining entries to be processed.